# Separate window that is only a toolshelf?

Tags: interface

I am rigging a character with the BlenRig addon. This addon provides a lot of controls for the rig in the Toolshelf of the 3D view. In order to have easy access to them without having the toolshelf use up too much of my workspace, I have made a new window on my secondary screen and set it to be the 3D view as well with the toolshelf open. However, this means I am also displaying my 3D scene a second time, which impacts performance.

Is it possible to have a window that is only the toolshelf panel without having to display my scene again? Or is panning to not show any model the best I can do?

[image]

Comment: Something like moving it to the properties area? `bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'`

Comment: AFAIK Blender's api doesn't allow to have the toolshelf in a separate window (as a fanatic multi-monitor user I'd like to see separate toolshelfs myself). One thing you *could* try is to maximize the toolshelf by hovering the mouse over it and then pressing Ctrl+Up-Arrow. I don't know if this will increase render performance in the other window.